# fill in required fields before button is enabled in form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form. I need all the required fields to have a value before the button can be enabled. At the moment, I have a button class on the continue button which disables it. I do not wish to use the required attribute or make it  a input field instead of a button. This is a form for a larger project and I have to use this button. Anyways, I want the button to remove the disabled class when all required fields have some value in it. It does not have to be specific value at this point in my project. right now I am only checking to make sure it is not empty. My JQuery is not working and I do not know why. I just want the button to remove the class when all the fields which are reqiured contain a value.. any value. Here is my code:

```
            <form id="customer-form" name="customer-form" action="" method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" id="f-name" name="full-name" placeholder="Full Name*" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Full Name*';}" onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'Full Name*') {this.placeholder = '';}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" id="job" name="job" placeholder="Profession / Job Title*" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Profession / Job Title*';}" onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'Profession / Job Title*') {this.placeholder = '';}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" name="company-name" placeholder="Company Name*" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Company Name*';}" onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'Company Name*') {this.placeholder = '';}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" name="project-name" placeholder="Project Name" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Project Name';}" onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'Project Name') {this.placeholder = '';}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone*" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Phone*';}" onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'Phone*') {this.placeholder = '';}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" name="email-address" placeholder="Email Address*" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Email Address*';}" onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'Email Address*') {this.placeholder = '';}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                        <span>Date of Request*</span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Select a Date" class="input-type-date datepicker-here" data-language="en" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Select a Date';}" onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'Select a Date') {this.placeholder = '';}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                        <span>Preferred Time of Contact*</span>
                        <select>
                            <option>Morning</option>
                            <option>Afternoon</option>
                            <option>Evening</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                        <span>Contact Preference*</span>
                        <label for="phone">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="contact-pref" id="phone"> Phone
                        </label>
                        <label for="email">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="contact-pref" id="email"> Email
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                        <p>Rheem Applications Engineers will provide a detailed sizing &amp; product selection report. <strong>Please check your preferences below</strong> for additional information to be included in your sizing report.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                            <label for="spec-st">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="info-pref" id="spec-st"> Specification Street</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                            <label for="parts-n-kits">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="info-pref" id="parts-n-kits"> Parts &amp; Kits List</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                            <label for="piping">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="info-pref" id="piping"> Piping Diagram</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                            <label for="prod-opt">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="info-pref" id="prod-opt"> Product Options</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                            <label for="energy-save">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="info-pref" id="energy-save"> Energy Savings Information</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                            <label for="revit">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="info-pref" id="revit"> Revit Files</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12"><button class="btn-primary disabled" type="submit" id="continue1">CONTINUE</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

And here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form > input').keyup(function() {
    var empty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });
    if (empty) {
        $('#continue1').addClass("disabled")
    } else {
        $('#continue1').removeClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Have you looked into using the `required` attribute for the input? If you use that you can't submit the form with empty values. Here's a quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/anr7hp05/2/

Comment: @DanielD yes I have unfortunately I can not use this attribute. Also, I need the button to remove disabled class when the input felds are with value in them.

Comment: You have an answer @AriesAzad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  to loop over all of the inputs (use js, or jquery as a last resort) and see if the property `.value != ""` (I recommend nested `if`'s). If all of the inputs are not empty, then it will re-enable the button. You can also make it so that if at any point one of the `input`'s are empty, it will disable the button. Call your verifing function using `document.getElementById("thatid").onchange = myFunction(){ /*mycode*/}`

See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/seerypx4/

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle or codepen? I am not well versed with JS.

Comment: I will make a jsfiddle

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I just started building my rep haha.

Comment: Ignore the js field.

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors are wrong. `'form > input'` selects input tags which are direct descendants of form tags. You probably want `'form input'` which means the input tags can be any number of levels inside the form tag.

https://jsfiddle.net/0Lvmraz8/

As a tip, you should really use `console.log` to check that your variables are what you think they are. In this case, `console.log($('form > input'));` would have shown you that there were no elements.

Comment: Your JSFiddle throws an error when you click the button. @skyline3000

Comment: Also note if you have checkboxes that are required, those don't have a `val()` attribute, you need to see if they are checked.

Comment: @skyline3000 That has nothing to do with my comment.

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade I mean... obviously... it's the OP's code and the form isn't actually going to submit on JSFiddle. Clicking the button is irrelevent -- the issue was that the event handling wasn't working because of the incorrect selector.